# How does js destruct default values for function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```js
function houseDescriptor([houseColor = 'green', shutterColors = ['red']] = []) {
    console.log(houseColor, shutterColors);
}

houseDescriptor('nbh');
```

Why console prints: n b

How its work?

Why if I pass string I don't have errors, but if I use houseDescriptor(123), I got an error?

Comment: a string is an iterable, which is destructured by the array.

Comment: `var [a,b,c] = "foo"; console.log(a, b, c);`.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are treated iterables and numbers are not. It's doing index based destructuring on your string, that's why only printing n and b.

[Have a look at listed iterables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)

Answer (score 1):

```
function houseDescriptor([houseColor = 'green', shutterColors = ['red']] = [])
```

The above function accepts one argument of type array. So when you are passing 'nbh' as argument, it will treat as iterable and perform the destructuring on it.

The above code is equivalent to

```js
let [firstCharacter, secondCharacter] = 'Stack'; 
console.log(`firstCharacter: ${firstCharacter} , secondCharacter: ${secondCharacter}`)
```

Comment: *Iterable*, not array.